# How to load embedded font as InputStream from jar in java?

Tags: java, exception, fonts, jar, embedded-resource

If I run the application from Eclipse, then all be done. But If export it to jar i get an Exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source)
```

[Here is the package tree](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/pathp.png/)

[image]

And my code (In the `SzervizPrint.java` file):

```
InputStream istream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/SerpentineBolditalic.ttf");
Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, istream);
myFont = myFont.deriveFont(36.0f);
lblNewLabel.setFont(myFont);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SerpentineBolditalic.ttf
```

Should be:

```
SerpentineBoldItalic.ttf
```

(capital 'I')

While the local file system might not be case sensitive, `getResource(String)` most definitely is.